# Add click listener in a textview of an included layout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a layout(MenuLayout) in which I have a textView(Logout). I want to add a click listener in that textView. I am including this layout in another layout.

Here is the code

```
<p.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/FlyOutContainer">
<include
    layout="@layout/menuLayout"/>
<include
    layout="@layout/Home" />
```

I am writing code for click event for logout like this

```
TextView logout = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textViewLogout);


        logout.Click += delegate {
            Intent logOut = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(logOut);
        };
```

But Click event is not working.
can anyone tell me the solution where I am doing mistake.

Here is the [Link](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/04/19/fly-out-menu-xamarin-android/) of source code which i am using.

Comment: is this android ? if yes you are working on native android sdk and eclipse ?

Comment: yes this is in android but in xamarin (Language c#).

Answer (score 5):

Another way in Xamarin is:

```
TextView logout = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textViewLogout);

logout.Click += logout_Click;


void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent logOut1 = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));
    StartActivity(logOut1);
}
```

Edited: try using another name for your intent, just in case.

Comment: I did this but it is not working. m not able to click on the text

Comment: you can do `logout.Click +=` (then press tab key on your keyboard twice) to generate event, then paste in your code...

Comment: Still I am not able to click on any textView. please check this [link](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/04/19/fly-out-menu-xamarin-android/). this code I am using.

Comment: so maybe you need to handle different event like: `OnTouchEvent ` according to the link

Comment: I will try thank you for your support. if you find the solution then plz tell me

Comment: am also look for the same issue please let me know the way if any one is implemented please.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.logout_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your TextView:

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

In Andrioid using Java:

For `<include>` First Inflate your Layout like

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().from(this).inflate(R.layout.menuLayout, null)

Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);

btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Hope this Could give you a idea to convert into C# (Xamarin)